# Python: List static variables used inside a function

Tags: python

I want to define a function `random_func` with some arguments like `arg_1` and `arg_2` and some variables inside this function such as `arg_3`, `arg_4`.

How can I get a list of these arguments and parameters inside this function that starts with `arg_` and return their corresponding values.

For example:

I list all variables by using `dir()` and then join all values by calling `eval()` function.

```py
def random_func(arg_1, arg_2):
   arg_3 = "a"
   arg_4 = "b"
   list = [name for name in dir() if name.startswith("arg_")]
   return "-".join(eval(x) for x in list)
```

However, If I run, I get this error:

```
random_func(arg_1="one", arg_2="two")
>>> NameError: name 'arg_1' is not defined
```

Ideally I would get:

```
one-two-a-b
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside `random_func`? Or from outside? Because from outside, none of these are "static", they're all set live as locals when the function is called each time. You're clearly omitting context here (`tmp_1_base` doesn't exist anywhere in what you've shown); can you provide a [MCVE] of the broken code.

Comment: I really don't follow what you're asking. `arg_3` et al. can't even be passed to the constructor, so why call it an argument?

Comment: Something is off here. I've re-read the question another 3 times and I don't understand the end goal. This seems to me to be an XY problem. What exactly is the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: Python functions don't have static variables. Local variables are not attributes, thus not discoverable by `dir`, and cannot be discovered without using something like the `inspect` module.

Comment: This is complicated by the fact that you're doing `.join` with a generator expression, and a generator expression is evaluated within its own local scope.

Comment: @kaya3: Actually, it's probably better this way; presumably whatever locals are involved in processing the already existing locals shouldn't be included in the set of locals to process, so having them be in a separate scope is a good thing. If you tried to use the list comprehension solution on Python 2, it could easily break (because listcomps didn't have separate scope on Py2, while genexprs and other comprehensions did; this was normalized to separate scopes for all on Py3).

Comment: @kaya3 well, the elephant in the thread is `eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: **This is a terrible idea, and I suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).** If you keep reading, understand you're wandering off into the weeds, and probably not solving your real problem.

You can use `locals()` to get a *read only* view of the function's locals as a `dict`; it will give you access to both the name and the value without relying on `eval` (which is slow and more dangerous):

```python
def random_func(arg_1, arg_2):
    arg_3 = "a"
    arg_4 = "b"
    return "-".join([val for name, val in locals().items() if name.startswith("arg_")])

print(random_func("one", "two"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv/YplTwnUgtaT4JeIlLVNbKTdlO3W4tfHRkGcy8yDYZjppX3kOqXOeRDiLo6NX7g1JPdmX0K2gz0VsCnnGs6AhD8@Zr59WZwuwoA7rB4xsLk8aQAfBZhGV0KmwDDElobZ2CqoGzeH4D@FalYSndegvcE8jfZqi2KSwGr@n2FkhyWgrhGtTekN)

As you desired, this prints `one-two-a-b`, and it does it without relying on `eval` at all.

Comment: Whether or not `locals()` is read-only [is unspecified in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) - in Python 3.6.2 you can do `locals().clear()` in the REPL and it does actually delete all your variables, for example.

Comment: Nice answer, I've read about XY problem. I'll try and be more careful next time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @kaya3: "read only" here should be taken to mean "modifying it almost never does what you want". The only reason `locals().clear()` works in the REPL is that the REPL is operating at global scope, and that means `locals()` is equivalent to `globals()` (which can be modified with predictable behavior). Put that `locals().clear()` in a function (defined in the REPL or not), and it won't do much (`def test(a): locals().clear(); print(a)` will successfully print `abc` if you call `test("abc")`, even though you just told it to delete all the locals).

Comment: @capm not next time. Now. What you're trying to do doesn't make sense and is indicative of a problem